# Does the IP and/or MAC address change when reconnecting

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a TP-Link router at home. Does the IP address and/or Mac address change everytime I reconnect to it? Meaning when I leave and come back will they change? Or can they?

Comment: So when you looked at it, left, came back, and looked at it again, did it change?

Comment: Further reading on MAC addresses: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, Surely trying to verify it that way isn't scientific.....

Answer (score 5):

- MAC addresses generally never change (although they can sometimes be manually changed, but they are supposed to be globally unique and static).
- The IP address that your computer receives from the TP-Link router will probably be constant, as it is a private IP address (e.g., 192.168.1.42), assigned by the router to the computer (supposing you're using DHCP to get the IP address, but as you're asking it probably means that you didn't manually set an IP address...). As the MAC address of the PC does not change, the router will generally keep giving it the same address (but this is not *guaranteed*, it is only the *typical* behaviour of home routers).
- The "external" IP address that your router receives from the Internet service provider will likely change periodically (e.g., every day or every some days), and will also probably change each time you restart your router.

Comment: So if I'm seeing a different Mac address sometimes and then later in same day the previous one comes back that would mean a different cell phone possibly? My point here is I'm pretty sure my b.f. has a secret cell phone that he hides cause he's a cheater. And I get a diff Mac address every so often but not at same time as his normal cell. Could he change SIM card and would that produce another Mac address?

Comment: So you see on your TP-Link router, on the device list, that there is a device you don't recognize? The MAC address is NOT related to the SIM card but to the device -- changing the SIM in a phone would not change the MAC address. So a different MAC address would be another device. You can actually know who manufactures the unknown device from the first 3 bytes of the MAC address (list here: http://www.ieee.org/netstorage/standards/oui.txt). For example an address starting with 00:16:4E:..... would be a Nokia device, whereas 40:30:04:... would be something from Apple (iMac, iPhone, ...).

Comment: By the way: are you sure that nobody else has the password of your WiFi network (I guess that when you write about a "cell phone", it is a smartphone that connects to the WiFi of the TP-Link router)? You might actually try changing the password (WPA key) to see if the device with the unknown device comes back.

Comment: I did change password and gave it to my b.f. it still comes up. Thank u for all the information! It is very helpful!

Comment: @lisaashley Make sure you changed it to a good password, and that you're using an appropriate encryption protocol on your router (i.e., not WEP). Otherwise the same person (if not your boyfriend) could just crack it again and regain access. You can find tips on this online, especially here on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

The MAC address is a fixed value. Is does not change.
If you want you can compare it to a serial number for a network card.

The IP on the other hand **can** change. It does not have to change, but depending on the setting of your DHCP server the following will happen:

1. You configured a static IP. The IP depends on the settings on your computer. The DHCP server is ignored.
2. You used DHCP. You get a free address from a pool of IP addresses.

   - If you leave and come back weeks later the IP adress will have been released and you will get another one.  (So it will change).
   - If you get back before the DHCP lease time is up your computer will ask for an IP and it will get its old IP renewed. (so it does not change).

If you want you can use a DHCP server and reserve an IP address for a specific MAC. That way the computer with that MAC will always get the same IP from the DHCP server.

Comment: Thank u. And no my cell ip And Mac address don't or haven't changed but my roommates has been. Thank u for the answers!